# Returning the index value in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I know this should be obvious, but with previous similar questions I could not get a satisfying answer. 
Let's say I have a data frame with the index being peoples names and a few columns containing their data (height, male/female, DOB, etc.). Now I want the tallest person in my dataframe and return the corresponding index (their name). 
So I want the index corresponding to: `df['Height'].max()`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think `df['Height'].idmax()` ?

Comment: You can kinda cheat a little by using double `[[]]` : `df[['Height']].max()` will return a Series with index value and single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['Height']` would return a Serie.

Then you should use `df['Height'].argmax()` or `df['Height'].idxmax()` to get the corresponding index.

With the links to the documentation :

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argmax.html

Comment: Ha, that is it! Maybe it was my inexperienced search queries that didn't get me here. Easy as, thanks mate!